# Resize view to fit superview after transform

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard, transform

I have a innerview within a view, I have pinned innerview to view using autolayout.
Now I am rotating innerview using transform

```
self.innerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

After transform, innerview is showing outside.

How can I fit innerview to view after transform means innerview should not go beyond view.

Please have a look at attached images.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fit **innerview** into **outterview** Increase height constraint of your outer view while you transform inner view

```
self.innerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2))

self.outterViewHgtConst.constant = self.innerView.frame.height+40
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by one line code

```
superView.clipsToBounds = true
```

`superView` is view that your `innerView` added on that

OR

You can also find out this property from storyBoard too.

Select your `superView` and check on **Clip Subviews**

[image]

Comment: It will clip the innerview instead of fitting it into view, means some content of innerview will be lost. for exp. image(suppose innerview is an uiimageview) will be cropped